# How do I both change the shell and change the start-up script?-

Tags: bash, zsh

I am on an embedded distro running with the `opkg` entware package manager.  I have a `bash` install, and this does not support tab completion now or ever.  So, I am switching to `zsh`.

I've successfully switched to `zsh`, but in this stripped-down version of linux, the `rc` file that is read when starting up `zsh` via `exec zsh` after changing the shell does not automatically change.  It is still `~/.bashrc`, which is benign for the most part.

But, it breaks the `zsh` prompt.

```
\[\033[00;37m\]this-comp\[\033[01;31m\]: \[\033[01;37m\]$(echo -n "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}" | awk -F "/" '{
if (length($0) > 50) { if (NF>4) print $1 "/" $2 "/.../" $(NF-1) "/" $NF;
else if (NF>3) print $1 "/" $2 "/.../" $NF;
else print $1 "/.../" $NF; }
else print $0;}')/\[\033[00m\]
```

How do I configure or force the startup file to be `.zshrc` rather than `.bashrc` when changing the shell?  Otherwise, I'll have to modify the `.bashrc` script, which is provided by the device updater.

Comment: `zsh` will **never** read `.bashrc`. did you change any files (like the `rc` file)? you shouldn't be needing to run `exec zsh` **at all**

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I may very well be close to bricking my device; working on it for the first time.  Are you telling me there is a master `rc` file that switches the shells, and this could either be corrupted or malformed?  Do you know which file that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force the startup file to be .zshrc rather than .bashrc when changing the shell, you can use the --rcfile option when executing zsh. For example, you can use the command `exec zsh --rcfile ~/.zshrc` to ensure that the .zshrc file is read when zsh is launched. You can also use the -f option, which will execute the specified configuration file when zsh is started, as in `exec zsh -f ~/.zshrc`. Finally, you can set the ZDOTDIR environment variable, which will override the default configuration directory, with the command `export ZDOTDIR=~/.zshrc.`